# Customize list filter

Tags: einstein-analytics, dashboard, filters, saql, tableau-crm

I have a list filter in dashboard there I have around 50 values. Now out of 50 there are five values which ‘Japan 20’, ‘Japan20’, ‘Japan2020’, ‘Japan-20’, ‘Japan_20’. Now in list filter I want to combine all these five filter criteria as one like “Japan 2020” so that when I select this in list filter I can see dashboard of all the five at once. I used case statement to change name to “Japan 2020” however variable count is not aggregate of all five. It’s taking count of first variable and in charts and tables I am seeing only blanks. Is there any way to fix this.

Comment: Could you please provide exact details of your current configuration (e.g. screenshots)? I'm not sure I understand - e.g. its relationship to Einstein Analytics.

Comment: Screenshot is not possible but I can elaboarate further. In dashboard build on Tableau CRM we used a list filter. Say for example, list filter has 10 values like A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J. Now Inwang C,D,E to be represented by one value K. Meaning that if C,D and E counts of values is 10 each then K should count as 30. When we select K we must see dashboard result of 30. This is what we want to do.